# Iphone checking subfolder existence, if exist delele subfolder, else and create subfolder

Tags: iphone

I'm new in Iphone programing, I need code to:

- check if a specific target subfolder exist in the document folder ?
- if target subfolder exist in document folder, I want to delete target subfolder
- if target subfolder does not exist in document folder, I want to create target subfolder in document folder

Thank's in advance for your help !

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `NSFileManager` class functionality.
To get Documents directory path:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];  // Get Documents directory
```

To check if directory (or file) exists at given path:

```
- (BOOL)fileExistsAtPath:(NSString *)path
- (BOOL)fileExistsAtPath:(NSString *)path isDirectory:(BOOL *)isDirectory
```

Remove item at path:

```
- (BOOL)removeItemAtPath:(NSString *)path error:(NSError **)error
```

Create directory at path:

```
- (BOOL)createDirectoryAtPath:(NSString *)path attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributes
```

For more details on these functions see NSFileManager class reference.