# How can I download an entire directory?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

Is it possible in Objective-C to download an entire directory to the documents directory so I would end up with a subfolder in the documents directory with a name of my choosing?  Then, is it possible to delete that directory and all its contents without looping through all the files?  Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is 'Yes, its possible' given that the directory and files in question are not larger than the available space on the device.  If you are talking about some text files or some images then I don't see a problem.

Not so sure about deleting all the contents without first getting a pointer to the files but that shouldn't take long in any case.

Were you looking for specific code examples as well?

There is a similar question, and answer [here].[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2162594/iphone-checking-subfolder-existence-if-exist-delele-subfolder-else-and-create-s)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot download entire folders over the internet, you would have to list the files and download them one by one.

You can use NSFileManager to create, read and remove files in your apps folder. You can delete a complete folder without having to loop through all the items in the folder.

- (BOOL)removeItemAtPath:(NSString *)path error:(NSError **)error;

Have a look at the NSFileManager documentation:
[NSFileManager documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Keep in mind that whenever you go outside the "sandbox" of your app, your app will be rejected by apple. So keep those files within your app's bundle.